# Simplify $f(x)=\sec (\tan^{-1} (\sin (\tan^{-1} x)))$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and find its inflection points

Tags: calculus, limits

> Simplify $f(x)=\sec (\tan^{-1} (\sin (\tan^{-1} x)))$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and find its inflection points, local extrema, x-intercepts, y-intercept, asymptotes, etc.

So the $y$-intercept is obviously $1$.

I'm not exactly sure if my simplification below is correct, but if it is, everything else that's required should be trivial for me (finding the local extrema and inflections points is very easy, though I'd like to know if there are any shortcuts other than evaluating the derivatives and relevant limits).

So I know by drawing a simple triangle that $\sin(\tan^{-1}x)) = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ and 
$\sec(\tan^{-1}x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}.$ But then, doesn't that mean that $\sec(\tan^{-1}(\sin(\tan^{-1}x)))=\sqrt{2-\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}}$?

Comment: Your math looks right to me. -- verified with GeoGebra

Comment: it is $1+x^2 $ how $1 + \frac{x^2}{x^2+1} = 2 - \frac{1}{1+x^2}$, it is sum not subtract

Comment: @AmerYR all I did was use the fact that $1=\dfrac{1+x^2}{1+x^2}$. If you add up the numerators, you'll get what I got.

Comment: Oh yea i see ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$f'(x)=\frac{x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2 \sqrt{\frac{2
   x^2+1}{x^2+1}}}$$ and $$f''(x)=-\frac{6 x^4+2 x^2-1}{\left(x^2+1\right)^4
   \left(\frac{2 x^2+1}{x^2+1}\right)^{3/2}}$$
Solve the equation $$f''(x)=0$$ to get inflection points.

Comment: Graubner, any tricks on how to find the second derivative "the smart way"? Also, can one simplify this root: $\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{7}}$?

Answer (score 0):

Note, you have $y=\sin(\tan^{-1}x)) = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$. Then,

$$\sec(\tan^{-1}(\sin(\tan^{-1}x)))=\sec(\tan^{-1}y)=\sqrt{1+y^2}$$
$$=\sqrt{1+\dfrac{x^2}{1+x^2}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1+2x^2}{1+x^2}}$$

Comment: I comment about that but he is correct adding one and subtract one then cancel

Answer (score 0):

You are right on computing $f(x)$. Now $f$ obviously is even function and is strictly monotone before and after origin. In fact it is strictly decreasing before it, has a minimum at origin $(0,1)$ and then strictely increasing after it. In both sides tends to $\sqrt 2$, so $y=\sqrt 2$ is horizontal asymptote in both side that $f$ increasingly tends to it. But for inflection points I have nothing to say without derivating, except we have two of them that are in $(\pm x_0,y_0)$. By what @Dr.SonnhardGraubner compute, we find $x_0 = \sqrt\frac{\sqrt 7 -1}{6}$, and $y_0 = f(x_0)$.